# Move range and get the opposite result

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

so i work on project and i have a problem
because i must control 2 audio elements ,the problem not this ,the problem is when i move  the range 
 the left the other audio element get the opposite value.

example:

> audio 1 and audio2 have the same value at the start

audio1,audio2=1

> but when I move the track and it's an DOM element and audio2 should not
>   have the same value as audio1

audio1=1.25  audio2=0.75

audio1=0.75 audio=1.25

> the interval is between 0 and 2 the middle value is 1

```
<input type="range" id="volume1" class="control-volume" min="0" max="2" value="1" list="gain-vals1" step="0.05" data-action="volume1" />
    <datalist id="gain-vals1">
        <option value="0" label="min">
        <option value="2" label="max">
    </datalist>


        <audio id="p" src="h.mp4" crossorigin="anonymous" ></audio>
        <audio id="n"src="v.mp4" crossorigin="anonymous" ></audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.clear();

    String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
        return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
    }

    // instigate our audio context

// for cross browser
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext ;
    const audioCtx = new AudioContext();

    const AudioContext1 = window.AudioContext ;
    const audioCtx1 = new AudioContext1();

    // load some sound
const audioElement = document.getElementById("p");
    const audioElement1 = document.getElementById("n");

const track = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
    const track1 = audioCtx1.createMediaElementSource(audioElement1);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const playButton = document.querySelector('.tape-controls-play');

    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    var vid1 = document.getElementById("myVideo1");

// play pause audio
playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // check if context is in suspended state (autoplay policy)
    if (audioCtx.state === 'suspended'||audioCtx1.state === 'suspended' ) {
        audioCtx.resume();
        audioCtx1.resume();
    }

    if (this.dataset.playing === 'false') {
        audioElement.play();
        audioElement1.play();
        vid.play();
        vid1.play();
        this.dataset.playing = 'true';
    // if track is playing pause it
    } else if (this.dataset.playing === 'true') {
        audioElement.pause();
        audioElement1.pause();
        vid.pause();
        vid1.pause();
        this.dataset.playing = 'false';
    }

    let state = this.getAttribute('aria-checked') === "true";
    this.setAttribute( 'aria-checked', state ? "false" : "true" );

}, false);


// if track ends // todo: to check
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', () => {
    playButton.dataset.playing = 'false';
    playButton.setAttribute( "aria-checked", "false" );
}, false);

    // volume
    const gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
    const gainNode1 = audioCtx1.createGain();
    //  const volumeControl = document.querySelector('[data-action="volume"]');
    const volumeControl1 = document.querySelector('[data-action="volume1"]');

    // panning
const pannerOptions = {pan: -1};
const panner = new StereoPannerNode(audioCtx, pannerOptions);


 /*   volumeControl.addEventListener('input', function() {
        gainNode.gain.value = this.value;
        panner.pan; console.log(this.value);

    }, false);*/
    //panning2///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    const pannerOptions1 = {pan: 1};
    const panner1 = new StereoPannerNode(audioCtx1, pannerOptions1);

  /*  const pannerControl1 = document.querySelector('[data-action="panner1"]');
    pannerControl1.addEventListener('input', function() {
        panner1.pan.value = this.value;
        console.log(this.value);

    }, false);*/
    var i=1;
    var k=1;
    let f1 =null;
    var  f2=null;
var g=null;
// is just a try not a correct code 
    volumeControl1.addEventListener('input', function() {
        f1=gainNode.gain.value;
        f2=gainNode1.gain.value;
        panner1.pan;
        panner.pan;
        g=this.value;

            f1=g;
            console.log(g);

               var n = g.toString();
        console.log(n.match(/0./g));

            if((n.charAt(0)==='0')){
            f1=g;
            //console.log(g);

            n=n.replaceAt(n.indexOf('.')-1,'1');
              var g2 = parseFloat(n);
               f2=g2;
             //  console.log(g2);
            }else
            if((n.charAt(0)==='2') ||(n.match(/1./g))){
                      f2=g;
                      n=n.replaceAt(n.indexOf('.')-1,'0');
                      n=n.replace('2','0')
                     var g3 = parseFloat(n);
                     f1=g3;
                }
            else
            if(n.charAt(0)==='1') {
                    f1=g;
                    f2=g;
                }

            console.log("v "+f1+"  v2  "+f2);


        /* else
                {
            gainNode1.gain.value = this.value;
            panner1.pan;
            panner.pan;
            gainNode.gain.value=this.value;
            console.log(this.value);}

    */
    }, false);



////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    track.connect(panner).connect(gainNode).connect(audioCtx.destination);
   track1.connect(panner1).connect(gainNode1).connect(audioCtx1.destination);

</script>
```

if anyone can help me find the solution to this problem I will be grateful tnx

Comment: Are you sure this line `const audioCtx1 = new AudioContext1();` is the same as in your script? because there is no global object called `AudioContext1`.

Comment: no problem with this line is correct the problem i what i said in the post

Comment: have you check this line `else if((n.charAt(0)==='2') ||(n.match(/1./g))){` because it seems like you are looking for 2 and also 1 in the string, which means that the last case ` else if(n.charAt(0)==='1') {` will not be executed. Did you perhaps meant for the matching to be `n.match(/2./g)` ?

Comment: no if n string is 1, then the 2 audio elements have the same value

Comment: What do you mean by `but when I move the track and it's an DOM element and audio2 should not have the same value as audio1`, specifically `but when I move the track and it's an DOM element `?, it makes it harder to pin-point exactly what you want.